# MySQL pivote style query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a mysql pivote style query for a google column chart. I would like the 'debit' data to appear under the 'transDesc' description but it always displays as 0. Im fairly new to this platform so could anyone tell me if I'm on the right track?

```
SELECT
    view_monthly_chart.pay_month, view_monthly_chart.transDesc AS Transaction,
    IF(view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Bills', `debit`, 0) AS bills,
    IF(view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Misc', `debit`, 0) AS misc,
    IF(view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Inc', `debit`, 0) AS inc,
    IF(view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Bank Trans', `debit`, 0) AS bank_trans
FROM view_monthly_chart 
GROUP BY view_monthly_chart.pay_month, view_monthly_chart.transDesc
ORDER BY view_monthly_chart.pay_id DESC
```

[image]

The query is based on a view:

```
select `t1`.`pay_id` AS `pay_id`,`t3`.`pay_month` AS `pay_month`,`t2`.`Desc` AS `transDesc`,floor(sum(`t1`.`debit`)) AS `debit` 
from ((`transactions`.`tbltransaction` `t1` 
    left join `transactions`.`tbltransid` `t2` 
    on((`t1`.`trans_id` = `t2`.`id`))) 
    left join `transactions`.`tblpayid` `t3` 
    on((`t1`.`pay_id` = `t3`.`pay_id`))) 
where (`t2`.`Desc` is not null) 
group by `t1`.`pay_id`,`t3`.`pay_month`,`t2`.`Desc` 
order by `t1`.`pay_id` desc limit 24
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI SQL way to do control structures in a `SELECT`-statement is using `CASE WHEN … THEN … ELSE … END`

So something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
view_monthly_chart.pay_month, view_monthly_chart.transDesc AS Transaction,
CASE WHEN view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Bills' THEN debit ELSE 0 END AS bills,
CASE WHEN view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Misc' THEN debit ELSE 0 ENDAS misc,
CASE WHEN view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Inc' THEN debit ELSE 0 END AS inc,
CASE WHEN view_monthly_chart.transDesc = 'Bank Trans' THEN debit ELSE 0 END AS bank_trans
FROM view_monthly_chart 
GROUP BY view_monthly_chart.pay_month, view_monthly_chart.transDesc
ORDER BY view_monthly_chart.pay_id DESC
```

Comment: Hi Salient, I'm getting an error, "Unrecognised keyword near CASE" amounst others, with your CASE code in myphpadmin. I upgraded to the latest '4.6.6' but the error persists.

Comment: This seems inherent to phpmyadmin. Have you tried a different client such as the mysql workbench: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ ?

Comment: I have the query running now in Workbench but the debit columns are all still 0. I changed the second line of the 'CASE' 'ENDAS' to 'END AS'

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from `view_monthly_chart`?

Comment: It looks like you are missing the dots? `transDesc` ends with dots?